# Byte shifting / casting VB6

Tags: vb6, byte

I'm extremely unfamiliar with VB6 so please excuse the rookie question:

I'm attempting to turn a long into it's component bytes. In C it is simple because of the automatic truncation and the bitshift operators. For the life of me I cannot figure out how to do this in VB6.

Attempts so far have all generally looked something like this

```
sys1 = CByte(((sys & &HFF000000) / 16777216))   ' >> 24
sys2 = CByte(((sys & &HFF0000) / 65536))      ' >> 16
```

sys1 and sys2 are declared as `Byte` and sys is declared as `Long`

I'm getting a type mismatch exception when I try to do this. Anybody know how to convert a `Long` into 4 `Byte`s ??

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You divide correctly, but you forgot to mask out only the least significant bits.

Supply the word you want to divide into bytes, and the index (0 is least significant, 1 is next, etc.)

```
Private Function getByte(word As Long, index As Integer) As Byte
    Dim lTemp As Long
    ' shift the desired bits to the 8 least significant
    lTemp = word / (2 ^ (index * 8))
    ' perform a bit-mask to keep only the 8 least significant
    lTemp = lTemp And 255
    getByte = lTemp
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Found on [FreeVBCode.com](http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.asp?ID=2066). Not tested, sorry.

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" _
Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (Destination As Any, Source As Any, ByVal _
Length As Long)

Public Function LongToByteArray(ByVal lng as Long) as Byte()

'Example:
'dim bytArr() as Byte
'dim iCtr as Integer
'bytArr = LongToByteArray(90121)
'For iCtr = 0 to Ubound(bytArr)
   'Debug.Print bytArr(iCtr)
'Next
'******************************************
Dim ByteArray(0 to 3)as Byte
CopyMemory ByteArray(0), Byval VarPtr(Lng),Len(Lng) 
LongToByteArray = ByteArray

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert between simple value types and Byte arrays by combining UDTs and the `LSet` statement.

```
Option Explicit

Private Type DataBytes
    Bytes(3) As Byte
End Type

Private Type DataLong
    Long As Long
End Type

Private DB As DataBytes
Private DL As DataLong

Private Sub cmdBytesToLong_Click()
    Dim I As Integer

    For I = 0 To 3
        DB.Bytes(I) = CByte("&H" & txtBytes(I).Text)
    Next
    LSet DL = DB
    txtLong.Text = CStr(DL.Long)

    txtBytes(0).SetFocus
End Sub

Private Sub cmdLongToBytes_Click()
    Dim I As Integer

    DL.Long = CLng(txtLong.Text)
    LSet DB = DL
    For I = 0 To 3
        txtBytes(I).Text = Right$("0" & Hex$(DB.Bytes(I)), 2)
    Next

    txtLong.SetFocus
End Sub
```